# How to generate unique ids in react. js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unique-key

I have a render function in the component which is responsible to render a controls on page. So far it is working fine.

```
render()
{
render 
(
{this.state.Inputs.map(input => {
if (input.CODE === "VARIABLE") {
  return (
    <div className="row p-1">
      <div className="col-sm-4">
        <label>
          <b>{input.LABEL_NAME}</b>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        {this.renderControl(input.WIDGET_TYPE)}
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
})
)
}
```

and below is my renderControl() function. I want to generate unique ids for each control when I am rendering it on page. I am not sure how to do this. Could you please help. Thanks in advance.

```
renderControl = controlName => {
  switch (controlName) {
    case "INTEGER":
    case "TEXTBOX":
    case "MEDIUM_TEXTBOX":
    case "NUMBER":
      return <input type="text" width="70%" className="txtSize" />;
    case "DROPDOWN":
    case "DIALOG":
      return <Dropdown />;
    case "DATE":
      return (
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      );
    case "DIALOG":
      return <Dropdown />;
    case "BOOLEAN":
      return (
        <div className="some-class">
          <input type="radio" className="radio" name="x" value="y" id="y" />
          <label htmlFor="y">Yes</label>
          <input type="radio" className="radio" name="x" value="z" id="z" />
          <label htmlFor="z">No</label>
        </div>
      );
    default:
      return;
  }
};
```

Comment: Pass it the index from map function.

Comment: @ritaj could you please help with example. Thanks

Comment: Sure, posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the following

```
render()
{
render 
(
{this.state.Inputs.map((input,key) => {
                if(input.ROW_CLASS_CODE === "MODEL_VARIABLE"){
                    return (
                        <div className="row p-1">
                        <div className="col-sm-4">
                        <label ><b>{input.LABEL_NAME }</b></label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6">
                        {this.renderControl(input.WIDGET_TYPE,key)} 
                        <br></br>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                            )
                }
})
)
}


renderControl = (controlName,key) =>{
        switch(controlName) {
            case 'INTEGER_FIELD':
            case 'SMALL_TEXTBOX':
            case 'PERCENTAGE':
            case 'MEDIUM_TEXTBOX':
            case 'REAL_NUMBER':
                case 'MONEY':
                return <input type="text" key={key} width="70%" className="txtSize" ></input>;
            case 'NARROW_DROPDOWN':
            case 'SELECTION_DIALOG':
                return (<Dropdown key={key}></Dropdown>);
            case 'DATE_FIELD':
                return (<DatePicker key={key}
                    selected={this.state.startDate}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />)
            case 'SELECTION_DIALOG':
                return <Dropdown key={key}></Dropdown>;
            case 'BOOLEAN_FIELD':
                return (<div className="some-class" key={key}>
                <input type="radio" className="radio" name="x" value="y" id="y" />
                <label htmlFor="y">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" className="radio" name="x" value="z" id="z" />
                <label htmlFor="z">No</label>
              </div>);
            default:
              return ;
          }
    }`
```

Comment: You are missing to pass key to renderControl function. I have done the same as per your  answer. But now control itself in not getting rendered. Prior to adding key in map function atleast I was getting controls on page.

Answer (score 0):

Change these 4 lines:

```
this.state.Inputs.map((input, index) =>
```

```
{this.renderControl(input.WIDGET_TYPE, index)}
```

```
renderControl = (controlName, index)
```

```
return <input type="text" key={index} width="70%" className="txtSize" ></input>;
```

Comment: I have done the same as per your code and below answer. But now control itself in not getting rendered. Prior to adding index in map function atleast I was getting controls on page.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a unique identifier from the input object, assuming LABEL_NAME is unique.
If not then pass the index from the map function.

```
{this.state.Inputs.map((input, index) => {
if (input.ROW_CLASS_CODE === "MODEL_VARIABLE") {
  return (
    <div className="row p-1" key={input.LABEL_NAME}> // Change this line
      <div className="col-sm-4">
        <label>
          <b>{input.LABEL_NAME}</b>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        {this.renderControl(input.WIDGET_TYPE)}
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Karan I did not get the answer. My label name is unique across the whole page. How to use above code exactly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to pass a unique id as a Key in every item when you return from the map function. In your case, the unique id is Label Name. <div className="row p-1" key={input.LABEL_NAME}>

Comment: But how does it make diff. I can not see ids generated for controls in console. Thanks

Comment: A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements. More on - https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html